# Blank sent to default printer on RDP Win2008R2 with mapped printing

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, remote-desktop, printing, remote-desktop-services

I’ve got an issue with a terminal server running Win2008R2 Enterprise SP1. 
My users have remote print mapping enabled (as it is imperative for their day-to-day duties). When they log in, RDP will send a blank document to their default printer. I've seen this problem before but have been unable to resolve the issue thus far.

I've installed all the latest windows updates on the server and user machines range from win7-win8.1 but they all produce the same symptoms.

This happens to users who have PDFprinter as their default and it happens to myself (win8.1) with OneNote2013 as my default. However, when I set my default printer to a physical one, there's no issue.

I've trawled online but have been unable to come up with anything other than installing some KB hotfixes, but these are already installed and have no effect. I can't really update drivers either, as they're using whatever comes with OneNote or PDFPrinter.

Comment: Might be a permissions issue. Does it happen when you connect as the server administrator?

Comment: yes, happens regardless of who logs in

Comment: What happens if you [disable Remote Desktop Easy Print](http://serverfault.com/a/523888/205065)?

Comment: Is there any chance installing those PDFprinter and OneNote2013 "printers" on the RDP server?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows Server 2008 Remote Desktop printing blank pages](https://serverfault.com/questions/147769/windows-server-2008-remote-desktop-printing-blank-pages)